# Как убрать кавычки при выводе

Tags: python

```
import json

from pprint import pprint
key_word = ['ExtensionAttribute1', 'ExtensionAttribute12', 'ExtensionAttribute13']

for i in key_word:

   word = i

   dct = {
        "Name": f"{word}",
        "FriendlyName": f"{word}",
        "Type": 1,
        "ApiDataType": 1,
        "APIDataMaxLength": 0,
        "Indexed": "false",
        "IncludeInDefaultResponse": "true"

   }
   print(dct)
```

Проблема в том что я хочу false и true вывести без ковычек. Но тогда питон ругается. Требует с большой буквы. Я попробовал strip(). Не помогло. Подскажите как правильно убрать ковычки при выводе???

Comment: 1) вывести где? В строке такого вида, но без кавычек: `"{'Name': 'ExtensionAttribute1', 'FriendlyName': 'ExtensionAttribute1', 'Type': 1, 'ApiDataType': 1, 'APIDataMaxLength': 0, 'Indexed': 'false', 'IncludeInDefaultResponse': 'true'}"`? Зачем тогда это нужно? 2) кусок кода вообще непонятный. Зачем цикл тут? Поместите нормальный минимальный пример с проблемой. 3) А почему вы о себе в мужском роде пишете? Раз профессия "программист", то и род строго мужской? 4) "кАвычки" правильно. Почему все через О пишут, не понимаю.

Comment: 'Indexed': 'true' надо 'Indexed': true

Comment: Покажите нормальный код. Где в приведённом коде здесь вывод `"Indexed": "true"`? И еще раз - какая цель данного желания? Просто так, или есть какое-то применение?

Comment: У меня, кстати, нормально без кавычек выводится. Так что давайте код ваш целевой.

Comment: Это весь код!!!

Comment: {'Name': 'ExtensionAttribute1', 'FriendlyName': 'ExtensionAttribute1', 'Type': 1, 'ApiDataType': 1, 'APIDataMaxLength': 0, 'Indexed': 'false', 'IncludeInDefaultResponse': 'true'} так у меня выводит пайчарме

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137928/discussion-between--and--).

Comment: Кроме ответа ниже можно ещё замену в словаре сделать, если устроит: `for key, value in dct.items():
       if value == "true":
           dct[key] = True
       if value == "false":
           dct[key] = False`

Comment: Как вариант, выводить поля по-отдельности и форматировать их как душе угодно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В коде пишите в соответствии с синтаксисом Python: `True` и `False` с большой буквы. Если вам нужно где-то с маленькой буквы, значит видимо вам нужен json, а не просто Python словарь. А раз нужен json, то используйте функцию `json.dumps` для конвертации в json, тогда и кавычки будут правильные (двойные, а не одинарные), и булевые значения с маленькой буквы:

```
import json

key_word = ['ExtensionAttribute1', 'ExtensionAttribute12', 'ExtensionAttribute13']

for word in key_word:
   dct = {
        "Name": word,
        "FriendlyName": word,
        "Type": 1,
        "ApiDataType": 1,
        "APIDataMaxLength": 0,
        "Indexed": False,
        "IncludeInDefaultResponse": True

   }
   print(json.dumps(dct))
```

Результат

```json
{"Name": "ExtensionAttribute1", "FriendlyName": "ExtensionAttribute1", "Type": 1, "ApiDataType": 1, "APIDataMaxLength": 0, "Indexed": false, "IncludeInDefaultResponse": true}
{"Name": "ExtensionAttribute12", "FriendlyName": "ExtensionAttribute12", "Type": 1, "ApiDataType": 1, "APIDataMaxLength": 0, "Indexed": false, "IncludeInDefaultResponse": true}
{"Name": "ExtensionAttribute13", "FriendlyName": "ExtensionAttribute13", "Type": 1, "ApiDataType": 1, "APIDataMaxLength": 0, "Indexed": false, "IncludeInDefaultResponse": true}
```

Comment: Вопрос в том, как сделать, если в коде (и в реальном словаре, например) так, как есть сейчас: `"Indexed": "false"`? Кроме идеи вывести всё куда-то (условно: файл) без отправки в стандартный выходной поток, а потом просто .replace сделать `"false"` на `false` и после этого - на печать, пока ничего не пришло в голову.

Comment: @Сергей в коде никак не сделать, и не нужно это пытаться сделать, на самом деле нужен просто json. У автора вопроса просто [ошибка X Y](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/1365).

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. Я потому его и спрашивал упорно, так как странно постановка задачи выглядела. Спасибо за решение.

Comment: Либо он наоборот из `json`-стиля хочет в питоновские `True` и `False` перевести, поди пойми